# Comparing two LIKE conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-like

Are these `LIKE` conditions the same:

```
Phone LIKE '%[()-. ]%'
```

and

```
Phone LIKE '%(%' OR Phone LIKE '%-%' OR Phone LIKE '%.%' OR Phone LIKE '% %'
```

I got results from the first one less than the second one. Any idea?

Comment: If you got different results for each query then I would say that tells you they are **not** the same.

Comment: The quoted text can be interpreted differently. You may want to explain the concrete meaning linguistically.

Comment: @Ek0nomik that is the reason I need help, me, newbie, thought they are the same.

Comment: You also missed the right parenthesis `)` in the second query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting different results is that `-` when used in `[]` represents a range of characters. It thinks you're asking for anything that has a `(`, `(space)` or any character between `)` and `.`. Try using the `ESCAPE` clause:

```
Phone LIKE '%[()=-. ]%' ESCAPE '='
```

This instructs SQL server that the `=` character is to be used as an escape character, and then by putting `=` before your `-`, the `-` is no longer interpreted as a range indicator.

I've never used the `ESCAPE` clause, so you may need to experiment. But this is the correct idea.

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx